# What science fantasy 80's series had a car that turned at right angles?

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a series in the 80s about a car.  It wasn't Knight Rider and I don't think it was Automan.  It was a cop or detective-type guy who had a car which, when it went round corners, did so at right angles.

He always dreaded getting in the car, and when the car went round the corner he was thrown up against the window inside.  My brother and I always watched it but it wasn't on for long... and everyone I ask thinks I'm nuts!

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you think it was Automan? I presume you found [this thread](http://www.inthe00s.com/archive/inthe80s/bbs14/webBBS_14292.shtml) while searching?

Comment: They actually sold toys around this series. They were little model cars with a standard wind up motor as seen in Tomy toys. Fab :) Never forgot the car that turned at right angles!

Comment: The 'car' form of the vehicle was a Lamborghini Countach that was customized by George Barris (look him up if his name doesn't mean anything to you, he's done a lot of auto customizations that you probably know :) I talked to George for a bit at one of the Detroit Autoramas a few years ago (20? 30? something like that), and asked him how they DID that with the car, the right degree turns. He looked at me for a moment with one of those "you're not thinking it was REAL, are you?" looks, and when I passed, he told me that generally, what they'd do is go past the turn, burn a 270 degree turn, and

Answer (score 25):

It **was** *Automan*. There are clips of this right angle turn on YouTube:

Comment: Hehe. This is hilarious. I've no idea how it got cancelled...

Comment: Thanks guys!  I wasnt going mad! For some reason I did not remember the glowing suit! Ha !

Comment: @Fiona don't forget to accept the answer that you think is correct. For more info go here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Yep Automan.

There was another character, Cursor, who was a glowing dot.  Cursor drew things vector-style (like the car that can turn 90 degrees) and they became real.  Cursor could also redraw stuff, like redraw the car to be an airplane.

From memory the human got squashed up against the window the first time Automan was driving.  He said something like "How can you do a right angle turn like that", and Automan answered "You programmed me to make right angle turns" with a flashback to a second or two of a game like PacMan or something.